# Async Await vs CallBack in Express Production server

Tags: node.js, express

I was reading production best practices given in express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#dont-use-synchronous-functions), where they mentioned do not use synchronous functions. Now, earlier I used to write my controllers like this:

1. without async await, only call backs.

```js
exports.getSubjectById = (req, res) => {
    const subjectId = req.query.subjectId;
    Subject.findOne({
        subjectId: subjectId
    }, function (err, subjects) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json(err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(subjects);
    });
}
```

2. then I started writing like this using async but not await and call backs.

```js
exports.getSubjectById = async (req, res) => {
    const subjectId = req.query.subjectId;
    Subject.findOne({
        subjectId: subjectId
    }, function (err, subjects) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json(err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(subjects);
    });
}
```

3. then I finally wrote this async await and NO callbacks.

```js
exports.getSubjectById = async (req, res) => {
    const subjectId = req.query.subjectId;
    const subject = await Subject.findOne({
        subjectId: subjectId
    });

    if (!subject) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            error: "no subject found for this id"
        })
    } else {
        return res.status(200).json(subject);
    }
}
```

can anyone please tell me which one should I use as production best practice and difference between these methods?

Comment: They say don't use `synchronous` functions and NOT `Asynchronous`

Comment: @Anatoly , can you please tell me which one should I use?

Comment: Anyway the last one looks good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, number 3 is better, but you need to consider the exception case.
So, you need to add try catch when you call async function.

```js
exports.getSubjectById = async (req, res) => {
    const subjectId = req.query.subjectId;
    try {
        const subject = await Subject.findOne({
            subjectId: subjectId
        });

        if (!subject) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                error: "no subject found for this id"
            })
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json(subject);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // exception, maybe db is broken when query data
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).end("Exception")
    }
}
```

And about **don't use synchronous**, there is an example you could take a look.
If I want api send the response after 5 second delay, what should I do?

In Java, you maybe use sleep(5) to delay.
So you might use following code when you write node.js.

```js
exports.getSubjectById = async (req, res) => {
    const startTime = new Date().getTime()
    while(new Date().getTime() - startTime < 5000){}
    res.status(200).send("Success")
}
```

It'll work, but it'll block the thread.
In node.js, you should use `setTimeout` to simulate the delay 5 seconds.

```js
exports.getSubjectById = async (req, res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.status(200).send("Success")
    }, 5000)
}
```

Above example, `while loop` is synchronous function.
But `setTimeout` is asynchronous function.
Due to the mechanism of node.js, you should use asynchronous function instead of synchronous function.

Comment: I also updated answer about why avoid using synchronous function in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Solution number 3 is good and also, most importantly, correct practice. Accessing the database is asynchronous by itself, it returns a promise. If you use async / await, it will return exactly what you are requesting. Also you can write simple test, for example, the speed of execution for each...